# Book series - towns separated by energy storm

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Towns/cities are surrounded by a kind of swirling & confusing energy storm or field.  In my mind's eye it was blue/purple in color.  The towns/inhabited regions are in bubbles of normal environment.

This fantasy (or perhaps SF) world has special guides able to lead caravans between the towns/cities, without which the caravans would become hopelessly lost.

In one of the books, I think it's revealed that the energy fields between cities can charge people up with (magical?) power.  I think only the guides are able to use this power.

I vaguely associate this story with Roger Zelazny but I can't find anything in his bibliography that looks like this trilogy(?).

These books would have been published no later than the late '80s.

Comment: The caravans-between-worlds reminds me a little of Robert Wilfred Franson's [Shadow of the Ship](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0345306880/ref=kinw_rke_rti_1) , but that was explicitly different *planets* not different towns.

Comment: Unless that's a reveal late in the series, I am pretty sure that this is not a duplicate.  However, "magicians who tap into a computer grid" does ring a bell.  Do you have a name/author for that story?

OK, I agree with ImaginaryEvents.  The books I'm thinking of are the books of Flux and Anchor!  Thank you so much!

Comment: The books of Flux & Anchor by Jack Chalker is the answer I was looking for.